Custom Gutenberg block doesn't appear
I just followed this tutoriel to build a plugin that add a custom block to Gutenberg: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/getting-started/tutorial/
And it's work well.
But when i duplicate the PHP and json code to another plugin, the block doesn't appear in Gutenberg.
Here is the code:
    <?php
/**
 * Plugin Name:       Custom Block 2
 * Description:       Example block
 * Version:           1.0
 * Author:            Manu225
 * License:           GPL-2.0-or-later
 * License URI:       https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 * Text Domain:       custom-block-2
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

function create_block_custom_2_block_block_init() {
    register_block_type( __DIR__.'/block');
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_block_custom_2_block_block_init' );

And the block.json:
{
      "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
      "name": "create-block/custom-block-2",
      "version": "1.0",
      "title": "Custom Block 2",
      "category": "widgets",
      "icon": "hammer",
      "description": "Example of custom block.",
      "render": "file./render.php",
      "text-domain": "custom-block-2"
    }

The render.php file exist and just have some text without PHP.
I don't have any error in the console. I tried to add the block by the JS function registerBlockType, but it's not working too. I don't understand what is missing in my plugin to work like the first one generated with npx command line?
Thanks for help!

Silly question maybe, but did you activate the plugin?

Yes yes my plugin is active.
And the block is correctly added, cause i had an error in my JSON file previously, and the console said it. After fixing it there is no error, but still no block in gutenberg...

Did you perform the build step necessary to build the files?

Yes and it's works well.
But the issue appear when i duplicate the build folder and copy/paste the code of the main PHP file inside a new plugin. I did that cause there is a nodes_modules folder automatically created inside the 1st plugin, sizing around ~250mo and i don't no why ? (i try to copy it in my 2nd plugin, bu still not working..)

Don't duplicate the build folder. You should copy all the source files, including the package.json to the new plugin. Omit the node_modules folder as well. In the new plugin run npm install to create a fresh node_modules folder. FYI node_modules contains all the packages to be able to build your block and is required. Be sure that name in the block.json is different in the second plugin, otherwise you'll be registering two blocks with the same name, which won't work. Run npm run build or whatever build script is defined your package.json.

Ok i understand how it works.
But it's not very convenient to have all these node modules inside the plugin directory.
I don't understand why it's not downloaded somewhere outside and just used to build the prod files?

You could always try to install all the packages globally which should make them available across all your projects. But what you're describing is a very common way of development. And usually you don't publish the source and node_modules folders to the users.

Yeah i understand. But i have around 10 plugin and want to try to create a Gutenberg block for each one. So having around 250mo of node_modules inside every folder isn't very optimized.
I'll try to install packages outside and see if it's work. Thanks for your help!
